# SAPUI5 - Clearing valueState of input fields in ui.table

Tags: sapui5

I'm having troubles resetting the valueState of input fields contained in a table cell. I'm clearing the model so the data is reset but the valueState is set on the view so it persists.

I've tried getting the input field byId and setting the value state as "None" but that doesn't affect the cells of the table.

Does anyone have an idea of how this can be achieved?

[Image of cell with value state "Error"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8TNG.png)

Comment: do you set your value state also over a model?

Comment: @bkr No, is that a possibility? It would be great if you could link to an example.

Comment: How do you set the valueState? Just set it to "None" the same way. Worst case over the table rows and cells after you clear the model...

Comment: @Erch I tried to do that but I couldn't make it work. Do you have an example where you loop through a table and maintain the cell view?

Comment: @BirgirSnorrason Did https://answers.sap.com/answers/13424774/view.html help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really don't want to work with data model, you can just loop over the table and set the ValueState to None.

Code Example:

```
var aRows, aCells;
aRows = this.byId("table.id").getRows();
for ( var i = 0; aRows.length; i++) {
    aCells = aRows[i].getCells();
    for ( var j = 0; aCells.length; j++) {
        if ( aCells[j] is an input element ) {
            aCells[j].setValueState(sap.ui.core.ValueState.None);
        }
    }
}
```